# Which distribution?

Tags: c#

best distro  for 2 GB ram, i3, 500 GB. I am currently run win7 on it. I have never tried Linux or Unix except Ubuntu in my school. I do not have many needs. Will Ubuntu lag in above system requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Without any doubt, just go for Ubuntu. Get the latest version!

> Why Ubuntu?
>
> its good for newbies. Easy to use. Cli friendly!

`its amazingly compatible with all drivers and graphic engines.`

> it has a big support community, that means you'll get all your queries, solved in seconds.

`its a beautiful distro and gets frequent updates`

> it can work smoothly with 2gb of ram. No probs there.

Comment: Respected sir, Did 500 GB will okay for downloading certain things from app center? Means extra software download apart from preinstalled ones?

Comment: 500gb is more than enough, an optimum ubuntu installation would require as less as 20gb for smooth functioning of resource heavy apps. My experience says 90 to 100gb would be more than enough.